# JQuery code wont work in my appended HTML

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have this appended textbox when I clicked a button, but .datepicker code in jquery wont work, but in a normal textbox, it works.

How can my .datepicker work in my Jquery? This is the sample jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fqjvLxn1/14/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append("<input type='text' class='asd datepicker'>");
    });
  } );


  </script>
</head>
<body>


<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<p>(.datepicker wont work here when I clicked a Button) </p>
<input type='text' class='asd2 datepicker'>(But works here)

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move your script to end of body or wrap it with document.ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call again datepicker function. 
Because you are calling once in document ready. This fragment is getting executed right after the page has loaded. Therefore, your dynamic datepickers are not there yet. You need to call $(YourElementSelector).datepicker() on each newly-inserted element

```
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append("<input type='text' class='asd datepicker'>");
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move your jQuery code at the end of `body`. jQuery does not know about new/appended elements after initial page load so you will have to use `document` to search those elements. Check out this snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="btn1">Append text</button>
  <p>(.datepicker wont work here when I clicked a Button) </p>
  <input type='text' class='asd2 datepicker'>(But works here)

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker();
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("p").append("<input type='text' class='asd datepicker' id='show'>");
      });
      $(document).on("focus", ".asd", function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```